# VBA Referencing SplitRow/SplitColumn

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will select first cell under SplitRow and next to SplitColumn (picture one). It is a very easy task that I have solved with comand `Cells(ActiveWindow.SplitRow+1, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn+1).Select`

But then I have run into a problem with hidden rows. I did some digging and was able to solve the problem with following code `Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Offset(ActiveWindow.SplitRow,ActiveWindow.SplitColumn).Select`

So far so good but I did some testing and this code stopped working. I have found out that if I freeze the panes (as it is in the picture) and then hide the first two rows the code above will not work because ActiveWindow.SplitRow will return 6, but if I hide the first two rows first and then freeze the panes ActiveWindow.SplitRow will return 4.

Is there any way how to reference the cell under the frozen panes regardless the order of actions of freezing the panes and hiding the rows?
[image]

Comment: I happen to check your profile. I rarely say this but seems like you are not aware of [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Please note that accepting answers are not mandatory though. The above link is only FYI in case you are not aware :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = ActiveWindow.SplitRow To Rows.Count
        If Not Intersect(Rows(i), ActiveWindow.VisibleRange) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah that works for both cases. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Reference First Not Frozen Cell

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RefFirstNotFrozenTEST()
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = RefFirstNotFrozen(ActiveWindow)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox fCell.Address
End Sub

Function RefFirstNotFrozen( _
    ByVal wind As Window) _
As Range
    If wind Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With wind
        .ScrollColumn = 1
        .ScrollRow = 1
        Set RefFirstNotFrozen = .VisibleRange.Cells(1)
    End With
End Function
```